# Why do we treat weight as acting on the object?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, free-body-diagram, weight

When drawing force diagrams I am really struggling to understand why we put the weight of an object as a force acting *on* it, rather than as a force acting on whatever else there is around it.

For example, if we have a book on a table, and are drawing two separate force diagrams for the forces acting on each object, then surely the weight of the book is a force acting on the table, not the book?

Or if you model a diagram of a person standing, it feels wrong to label the weight as acting on the person, when surely it is acting on the floor? And the force acting on the person is the reaction of the floor to the weight?

It all just feels a bit off! Please can someone offer some help to correct my intuition?

(I should add that I kind of understand that the weight of an object does act on it, insofar as gravity does pull things down...)

Comment: [this](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/derivation-of-the-change-of-air-pressure-with-height.977116/page-2) will surely help you.

Answer (score 5):

> Please can someone offer some help to correct my intuition?

Drawing a free-body diagram is an important exercise that takes some practice to get right. I have found that the following systematic approach works well, I will use your book on a table scenario to demonstrate.

First, list all objects involved in the scenario. Here it is the book, the table, and the earth. The book and table are explicitly mentioned, and usually we must include the earth also unless we are specifically told that the scenario is in space far from the earth.

Second, describe all of the significant interactions in the scenario. This involves finding pairs of objects that interact and the mechanism of their interaction. For example, here we get:

1. The earth and the book interact by gravity
2. The earth and the table interact by gravity
3. The table and the book interact by contact
4. The table and the earth interact by contact

Notice what is not included: there is no contact interaction between the earth and the book because they are not touching and there is no gravitational interaction between the book and the table because it is so small that we are just going to ignore it. Notice also that sometimes you can have multiple different interactions between the same objects, such as 2 and 4 which are two different interactions (gravity and contact) between the earth and the table. Deciding which interactions to analyze can be challenging, but this approach is at least systematic.

Third, choose one object, and go back through the list and mark every time it occurs. So if we are analyzing the book then we would get:

1. The earth and the **book** interact by gravity
2. The earth and the table interact by gravity
3. The table and the **book** interact by contact
4. The table and the earth interact by contact

Fourth, draw the free body diagram for that object. The number of times that the object was marked in the list above is the number of forces that should be included on the free body diagram for that object. In this case the force from interaction 1 is the weight of the book and the force from interaction 3 is the normal force. The weight of the book is an interaction between the earth and the book so it would never show up on a free body diagram for the table.

I hope this helps. It is not fool-proof and does require some thought, but at least it is a systematic approach to free-body diagrams. Also, if you do multiple free body diagrams then the interactions identify 3rd law pairs of equal and opposite forces.

Answer (score 2):

[Dale's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/522329/179151) gives a great methodology for making free body diagrams, which are important for understanding the system in question. I wanted to specifically address the below question in a more "conceptual physics" way:

> For example, if we have a book on a table, and are drawing two separate force diagrams for the forces acting on each object, then surely the weight of the book is a force acting on the table, not the book?

The weight of the book, by definition, is the force of gravity acting *on the book*. So you cannot say "the weight of the book acts on the table".

Your confusion most likely lies in the fact that for the book laying on the table, the magnitude of the book's weight is equal to the magnitude of the force of interaction between the book and the table. In other words, you view the table as exactly supporting the book, and so you make the incorrect jump from "the table pushes on the book with a force that has a magnitude equal to its weight" to "the weight of the book acts on the table".

To the layperson in physics, these might not seem like different statements, but once you start getting into physics you need to realize the differences. Two forces having the same magnitude is not a sufficient condition for the forces to be the same force. The weight of an object only acts on that object. If forces of interaction happen to have the same magnitude of that weight, then that's fine, but you still have to recognize the difference in the forces.

Answer (score 1):

When we are drawing Free body diagram of a particular object we are only concerned with the the question that what forces are acting on the object and not with what force acting on the surrounding?

Why? Because to get the full knowledge of the dynamics of the object in question you just need to know the force (for acceleration), initial velocity, and initial position. And the rest is just some maths.

When we represent a book on the table and ask what forces are acting then we must include the gravitational force acting downward on the object and any other forces in knowledge (such as normal force, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

There are seveal other very nice answers here, but I want to focus very closely on "why do we say weight acts *on* the book?"

---

Let's conduct a thought experiment

> Slide the table (or other support) out from under the book leaving it unsupported. What happens to the book?

It falls down right? So it goes from not moving to moving downward which means it accelerated, and Newton's 1st and 2nd laws tell us that this means it is subject to a net force.

But ...

- the book is not in contact with any solid objects so that force doesn't include solid-contact forces
- the book *is* in the air so there are buoyant forces (wait until you get to the chapter on fluids...) but they point up and are way too small to account for this anyway

So there is some non-contact force acting *downward* on the book. Which we call the "weight".

---

The second un-stated question is "Why does day to day experience include "weight" as an effect on other objects?" and that is well covered by otehr answers, but I'll include a brief version here.

When the book is on the table it doesn't accelerate downward even though it's weight points down. That is because it is also subject to an upward force from the table (called "the normal force" among other things), and Newton's 3rd law tells us that the tabel is subject to an equal and oposite force from the book.

So the table "recieves" the weight of the book as the consequence of preventing gravity from pulling the book downward.

Answer (score 0):

> When drawing force diagrams I am really struggling to understand why
>   we put the weight of an object as a force acting on it, rather than as
>   a force acting on whatever else there is around it.

We do both. It depends on which free body diagram you are looking at. If it is a free body diagram of the object having the weight, it is shown as the force of gravity acting on the object. If it is a free body diagram of another object upon which the first object acts, it is shown as a force acting on the other object.

> For example, if we have a book on a table, and are drawing two
>   separate force diagrams for the forces acting on each object, then
>   surely the weight of the book is a force acting on the table, not the
>   book?

The force of gravity is acting on the book. It is called its weight because we generally think of weight in terms of the reading of a scale upon which something is placed. But it is nonetheless the force of gravity acting on the book.

Below are free body diagrams (FBD) of a book a table upon which the book rests. Each free body diagram shows all the external forces acting on each object.

The FBD of the book shows the force of gravity acting on the book (aka its weight) and the equal and opposite reaction force of the table on the book.

The FBD of the table shows the weight of the book acting on the table, as well as the force of gravity acting on the table itself (its own weight). For equilibrium, the FBD also shows the reaction forces of the floor on the table (assumes four legs symmetrically arranged).

If we were to show a free body diagram of the floor, we would instead show those forces that are acting up on the table in the table FBD acting down on the floor for the floor FBD, as that is the force exerted by the table/book on the floor.

> Or if you model a diagram of a person standing, it feels wrong to
>   label the weight as acting on the person, when surely it is acting on
>   the floor? And the force acting on the person is the reaction of the
>   floor to the weight?

The "weight" acting on the person is the downward force of gravity on the person. The free body diagram of the person shows an equal and opposite reaction by the floor for equilibrium. If we were to show a free body diagram of the floor, the person's weight would be shown acting down on the floor, because the person becomes an external force acting on the floor.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If something is immovable then any gravity force acting on it does not matter, as there is surely an equal and opposite contact force that keeps it from moving. Thus the weight on non-moving bodies can be safely disregarded unless the *deformation* of objects is studied.